# The Moon locked me in secret room during Challange #3

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-afterbirth+

I'm in the middle of [challenge #3 Head Trauma](https://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Head_Trauma). I just used a *[XVIII - The Moon](https://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Cards_and_Runes#XVIII_-_The_Moon)* card and got transported to a [secret room](https://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Secret_Room). Now apparently I shouldn't be having any issues because according to gamepedia wiki The Moon card:

> [...] will open one random wall once inside the Secret Room, so you can leave even if you don't have any bombs available.

But my exit, on the right, is sealed shut:

> [image: my issue]

and I have no bombs left.

I would like to complete the challenge but I'm pretty sure using the *[debug console](https://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Debug_Console)* will negate everything.

Is this going to be the bane of my run? What options do I have?

Comment: Have you tried waiting 2 minutes?

Comment: @Studoku Waiting two min does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm calling glitch. The game is supposed to allow you to leave via one exit, but for some reason the exit it has chosen is linked directly to one of the "special rooms" which you haven't activated yet.

Since it's a special room the game will not allow you to access that auto exit without a bomb.

It's either that or there's an enemy inside of the room, but I don't see one.

locked in areas is rare in my experience but possible. I once got teleported randomly (curse pearl), into the middle of one of those rooms with the center blocked off by unbreakable blocks and no way of getting out without resetting.

Basically this run is now not able to be completed sadly.